# Efficiently matching two Flux

Tags: kotlin, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have two Flux with 2 different data types as shown below:

```
Flux<Dog> dogs = loadDogsFromFile()
Flux<Man> men = loadMenFromFile()

data class Dog(
    val name: String,
    val ownerName: String,
)


data class Man(
    val name: String,
    val dogOwnerName: String,
)
```

As you can see the one field we can use to match these two Flux objects is `dogOwnerName`. Right now this is how I am comparing them

```
val disposable = dogs.flatMap { dog ->
    men.map { man->
        val isEqual = comparator(dog, man)
        Triple(dog, man, isEqual)
    }
}.filter {x -> x.third === true }
```

This gets the job done but it is nowhere efficient, it keeps looping even after the desired fields are found and because of that, we have to use a `filter` operator to only get what we need.

**Edit**

Based on @marstran comment on the user input, I have large `JSON` files that contain `dogs` and `men` that I'm loading here:

```
Flux<Dog> dogs = loadDogsFromFile()
Flux<Man> men = loadMenFromFile()
```

After matching the dogs to their owners/men I'm building an object that I'm saving to the database like this:

```
val disposable = dogs.flatMap { dog ->
    men.map { man->
        val isEqual = comparator(dog, man)
        Triple(dog, man, isEqual)
    }
}.filter {x -> x.third === true }
 .map{(dog,man,isEqual) ->
  DogOwner(man,dog) 
}.doOnNext{dogOwner -> dogOwnerRepository.save(dogOwner)}
```

Comment: What exactly is you expected output? Can you give an example with some input and what the output should be?

Comment: @marstran the input can be a `Flux<Pair(dog,man)>`

Comment: That's a type. Please give some concrete input and output.

Comment: @marstran I have large `JSON` files containing containing `100k+ to 1m` `dogs` and `men`, I would like to match them and return an Object containing matches which will be saved to a database. With my current approach, it works but consuming a lot of resources, also, the fact that their should be a better way of doing this is killing me.

Comment: @marstran kindly see my edit.

Comment: Still no testdata...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using method `take(long n, boolean limitRequest)` from `Flux`:

```
public final Flux<T> take(long n,
                          boolean limitRequest)
Take only the first N values from this Flux, if available.
```

using it will allow you to break iterating over man once owner would be found.
https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#take-long-boolean-

Take a look at this java example. I assume that dog and his owner have same value.

```
 @Test
    void dog_owner_test() {
        int COUNT = 10000;
        Flux<Integer> dogs = Flux.range(0, COUNT);
        Flux<Integer> man = Flux.range(0, COUNT);

        dogs.flatMap(
            dog ->
                man.map(m -> Tuples.of(dog, m))
                    .filter(tuple -> tuple.getT1().equals(tuple.getT2()))
                    .map(tuple -> new DogOwner(tuple.getT1(), tuple.getT2()))
                    .take(1, true)
        )
            .doOnNext(System.out::println)
            // here you can save DogOwner to db
            .as(StepVerifier::create)
            .expectNextCount(COUNT)
            .verifyComplete();
    }

    private static class DogOwner {
        DogOwner(Integer dog, Integer owner) {
            this.dog = dog;
            this.owner = owner;
        }

        Integer dog;
        Integer owner;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "DogOwner{" +
                "dog=" + dog +
                ", owner=" + owner +
                '}';
        }
    }
```